# Como capturar o pressionamento de uma tecla com o programa rodando em segundo plano

Tags: java

O código que tenho até agora é esse:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();  
    Image image = new BufferedImage(10, 10, 10);
    String tooltip = "Oi amiguinho";  
    PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu("Pop Up");  

    TrayIcon icon = new TrayIcon(image, tooltip, menu);  
    try 
    {
        tray.add(icon);
    } 
    catch (AWTException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 


}
```

e eu gostaria de saber como posso capturar uma tecla pressionada pelo usuário mesmo com o programa rodando em segundo plano.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Quando se desenvolve uma aplicação utilizando os eventos "nativos" do Java, ela não reconhece quando está fora da JVM. Ou seja, rodando em segundo plano.

Aconselho que você dê uma olhada na [API JNativeHook](https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/), usei  há algum tempo para desenvolver aplicações que se comunicavam fora da JVM. Essa API resolve seu problema!

Answer (score -4):

```
    seuJTextField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {  
        public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e) {  
            if(e.getKeyCode() == java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {  
                //Aqui é seu código  
            }                 
        };  
    });
```

Comment: Mas onde eu adiciono  o `JTextField` ??

Comment: no escopo, instanciando

Comment: Desculpe, não consegui, poderia dar um exemplo completo ??