# Como capturar teclas com o programa minimizado

Tags: java

Estou fazendo um Chat e gostaria de que quando o usuário digitasse uma letra(que ele configuraria) reabrisse o Chat que estava minimizado.

Como eu faria para capturar uma tecla pressionada mesmo com o programa minimizado ??

Comment: possível duplicada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/83193/como-capturar-o-pressionamento-de-uma-tecla-com-o-programa-rodando-em-segundo-pl

Comment: @Brunno tem o mesmo intuito, mas aquela pergunta não tem uma resposta.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert eu lembrei de ter visto algo parecido hahaha'.. ai comentei só por desencargo de consciência :DD

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Mesmo não tendo uma resposta, se a pergunta foi feita pela mesma pessoa, [ela pode ser sinalizada como duplicada](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165933/251152).

Comment: Auto-duplicatas não são bem-vindas. Confira como oferecer uma recompensa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties

Comment: @DanielGomes desculpe nao tinha visto que era de mesmo AP.